# Error in ajax insert database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In each row, i want to add a editable td to insert "mavandon" into DATABASE dsdonhang. I read this on http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/ but it doesn't work :((

```
<script src="../lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>   
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){        
    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,idd) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveedit.php",
            type: "POST",
data:'column='+$(this).column+'&editval='+$(this).editableObj.innerHTML+'&idd='+$(this).idd,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                //alert ("hello");
            }
        error: function() {}    
       });
    }
});        
</script>
<?php $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM dsdonhang");            
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {$data[] = $row;}
    foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php $madon = $data[$k]["idd"];echo $k+1; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data[$k]["ngaydat"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data[$k]["hoten"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data[$k]["diachi"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data[$k]["sdt1"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data[$k]["donhang"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data[$k]["tongtien"]; ?>.000VN&#272;</td>
          <td><?php echo $data[$k]["nguoinhan"]; ?></td>
          <td contenteditable="true" onchange="saveToDatabase(this,'mavandon','<?php echo $madon; ?>')"><?php echo $data[$k]["mavandon"]; ?></td>
          <td><a href="donhang.php?id=<?php echo $data[$k]["idd"]; ?>&tc=<?php echo $data[$k]["sothamchieu"]; ?>">Xem</a></td>
        </tr>
<?php
  }            
?>
```

saveedit.php

```
<?php
require_once("../lib/connection.php");
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE dsdonhang set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  idd='".$_POST["idd"]."'");
?>
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the structure of dsdonhang table?

Comment: http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/ is a good tutorial . But what kind of issue you face.

Comment: what showing in console?

Comment: You can use `column` directly instead of  `$(this).column`. Please see that tutorial for this.

Comment: `it doesn't working` - is not a useful description of the problem - do some basic debugging, tell us what isn't working, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead

Comment: table structure:
idd:  int(11) PRIMARY
mavandon varchar(20) utf8_general_ci

Comment: td-s become editable, but cannot edit records in mysql database.
When reload page, nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

use `onblur` instead of `onchange`

```
<td contenteditable="true" onblur="saveToDatabase(this,'mavandon','<?php echo $madon; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$k]["mavandon"]; ?></td>
```

Comment: i use `onchange` instead of `onBlur` to avoid the ERROR "Uncaught ReferenceError: saveToDatabase is not defined"

Comment: Is the ajax triggered(check in the browser console)?

Comment: i dont know. how to check it?
when i open Console tab, nothing logged

Comment: Use FireFox Browser and install FireBug addon. After successful installation press F12 and see some panels there in the bottom of the browser. Click on the console tab then you can see the ajax call request and response. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Typo / incorrect while passing params in the ajax call. Modify it as mentioned below

```
add this in ajax call.
'&idd='+idd

Instead of this 
'&idd='+$(this).idd
```

Comment: Modify the td : <td contenteditable="true" onblur="saveToDatabase(this,'mavandon','<?php echo $madon; ?>')" onclick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $data[$k]["mavandon"]; ?></td>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){        
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,idd) {
     var data = {'column':$(this).column,'editval':$(editableObj).text(),'idd':$(this).idd };
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveedit.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatType: "json",
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(data){
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            console.log("received data=>"+data);
            alert ("hello");
        }
    error: function(err) {
       console.log("error=>"+err); //print error if exist
    }    
   });
}
});        
</script>
```

Comment: Did it alert anything?

Comment: Where are you calling saveToDatabase(); ?

Comment: `onchange="saveToDatabase(this,'mavandon','<?php echo $madon; ?>')"`, in the 9th <td>

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on line:
`data:{'column':$(this).column,'editval':$(editableObj).text(),'idd':$(this).idd},`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ur event is getting called.(u can check in firebug also.)
Pass parameters as
{column: $(this).column,editval:$(this).editableObj.innerHTML,idd:$(this).idd}