# Inline editable row to update each records in database mysql using ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

this question is relevant to [Error in ajax insert database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565300/error-in-ajax-insert-database/39565683). Many advices, but none of them helps.
You can see a demo: http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/
I have trouble in using ajax, PHP and mysql to edit records in database. 
The table `dsdonhang` has many records, each record performs a order. I want the last column to show a string (tracking shipping), called `mavandon`, and it can be edited inline, with `onBlur` trigger.
The ajax function send data with 2 parameters:

1. $idd: the row to edit
2. text: value to update

index.php:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM dsdonhang");            
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php $madon = $data[$k]["idd"];echo $k+1; ?></td>    
<td><?php echo $data[$k]["donhang"]; ?></td>        
<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="SOMETHING..."><?php echo $data[$k]["mavandon"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php            
}
?>
```

Structure of table `dsdonhang`:

idd int(11) PRIMARY NOT NULL

donhang varchar(50) NOT NULL

mavandon varchar(12) NOT NULL

If you have any idea or suggestion, please guide me. It will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Why load an array in the while loop and then process the array incorrectly. Why not just output the table lines in the while loop

Comment: It would be useful to connect to the database before trying to run a query against it

Comment: It would be a good idea if you [looked at how a `foreach` loop works](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) as well

Comment: sorry, i didnot copy `mysqli_connect ` function, i have already used it before

Comment: if use `while` instead of `foreach`, I cannot handle the `$idd`?!?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no reason to load an array and then process the array, when it can all be done in the while loop.

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM dsdonhang");            

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['idd'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['donhang'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="SOMETHING...">' . $row['mavandon'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, i got it. But the main problem is still not solved